# Properly declaring a template parameter - argument when the function definition is being explicitly specialized

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions, c++17, overloading

I have a class that looks like this: Foo is my class; FooBar is a bunch of different types of classes from a library that each have independent names.

**Foo.h**

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;

    // There many types, and many of these types have multiple constructors
    // All of the appropriate overloads are available here.
    template<class Type>
    FooBar<Type>& getFooBarByFullName( ... ) {
       // construct & return FooBar<Type>(...);
    }      

    // Then I have a hand full of overloaded function template declarations 
    // with a generic name to call the appropriate functions from above.
    // Each FooBar has different parameters, and FooBar is a class template.
    template<class Type, template<typename> class FooBar>
    FooBar<Type>&  getFooBar(...);
};

// Outside of any class I have a generic function template
template<class Other, class Type, template<typename> class FooBar, class... FP>
Type doSomething( some param A, some param B, some param C, FP... params ) {
    // Code here to work with Other using A, B & C

    FooBar<Type> fooBar = getFooBar<Type, FooBar>( params... );
    // do something to fooBar

    return value generated from fooBar;
}
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include **Foo.h**

template<class Type, template<typename> class FooBar>
FooBar<Type>&  getFooBar(...) {
    return {};
}

template<>
FooBar<int>& Foo::getFooBar( ... ) {
    return getFooBarByFullName( ... );
}

template<>
FooBar<short>& Foo::getFooBar( ... ) {
    return getFooBarByFullName( ... );
}

// etc...
```

---

One of the implementations that I'm working on has for one of its template parameter is a `class unary_op`.

I do not want to define any such class. I need to be able to pass either a function object, function pointer, lambda, or std::function to these functions as the `unary_op` class.

The problem I'm running into is if my declaration(s) in my header looks like this:

```
template<class IntType = int, class UnaryOp>
FooBar<IntType>& getFooBarByFullName( std::size_t count, double xmin, double xmax, UnaryOp fw ) {
    // Constructors last parameter is defined as a class UnaryOp; 
    // but can be any of a function object, function pointer, lambda, std::function<...> etc.
    FooBar<IntType> fooBar( count, xmin, xmax, fw ); 
}

// Then I can declare the appropriate generic declaration overload here
template<class Type, template<typename> class FooBar, class FuncOp>
FooBar<Type>& getFooBar( std::size_t count, double xmin, double xmax, FuncOp fw ); // Declaration only
```

However when I go to the cpp file to write the definitions explicit specialization using the provided appropriate overloaded declaration while trying to avoid ambiguity is where I get into trouble.

```
template<>
FooBar<int>& Foo::getFooBar( std::size_t count, double xmin, double xmax, ? ) {
    return getFooBarByFullName<int>( count, xmin, xmax, ? );
}

template<>
FooBar<short>& Foo:getFooBar( std::size_t count, double xmin, double xmax, ? ) {
    return getFooBarByFullName<short>( count, xmin, xmax, ? );
}
```

As you can see I don't know how to define the last parameter of type `class UnaryOp`. I would also like to be able to support that the caller can pass any of the types I mentioned above: `function object`, `function pointer`, `lambda`, `std::function<>` as the last parameter for the `UnaryOp`. I don't know where to go from here...

**Edit** - I forgot to mention that in my actual code; the two classes above have deleted default constructors; and all the class methods are static.

Comment: Sorry but... you're trying again to partial specialize a method?

Comment: Does your first template argument have a _default value_ ?

Comment: partial specialization of template function is not valid

Comment: @Max66 no not exactly. There are several overloaded declarations in the header. Then in the cpp file. They look like partial but they aren't. I believe these are called explicit specializations; but don't quote me on it... I do know that this pattern is working already, but I get into trouble when I have to added in this final piece of the puzzle for the unary op function object...

Comment: Oh in my original code; my methods are declared as static; and the class default constructor is deleted.

Comment: I refuse to accept that your code above is the minimal code exhibiting your problem. Often, when one actually creates a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the issues becomes clear (and the question is answered w/o need for SO).

Comment: An explicit specialization has no template parameters, so it deals only with concrete actual types, and cannot involve a placeholder like `UnaryOp` to stand for an entire category of actual types.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're actually asking, but it appears that your problem is to create an instantiatable yet generic function in your .cpp file. I think there are two options to solve this problem:

1. Abandon your plan: make these methods templates living only the .hpp file and taking `UnaryOp` as (deducible) template parameter.

   ```
   .hpp:
   template<typename Type, typename UnaryOp>
   Type Qoo(Type const&x, UnaryOp&&func)
   {
      // some simple/short code calling func()
   }
   ```
2. Implement a function overload for `UnaryOp` = `std::function` in your .cpp file and implement the general `UnaryOp` (lambda, functor, function pointer etc) as template in your .hpp file, calling the former using a `std::function` object created from whatever `UnaryOp` is.

   ```
   .hpp:
   template<typename Type>
   Type Qoo(Type const&, std::function<Type(Type)>&&);

   template<typename Type, typename UnaryOp>
   Type Qoo(Type const&x, UnaryOp&&func)
   {
      return Qoo(x, std::function<Type(Type)>{func});
   }

   .cpp
   template<typename Type>
   Type Qoo(Type const&t, std::function<Type(Type)>&&func);
   {
      // some lengthy code calling func()
   }
   // explicit instantiations
   template int Qoo(int const&, std::function<int(int)>&&);
   template short Qoo(short const&, std::function<short(short)>&&);
   ...
   ```

The second version allows pre-compilation, but generates overheads in case `UnaryOp`≠`std::function<>`.
The first solution avoids such overheads but exposes the full implementation to the .hpp file and does not offer the benefit of pre-compilation.

In similar situations, I tend to use the second version if the code implemented is substantial, such that the overhead of the `std::function` object can be tolerated, and the first version only for small code, which generally should be `inline` anyway.

Finally, note that in the .cpp file you don't need to define all the specialisations, but give the template and specify the explicit instantiations.

Comment: I was taking the random engines and distributions from the `<random>` header file. I ended up created two classes one for the engines and one for the distributions. Originally these classes had deleted constructor with static methods to retrieve each type by independent name. Later I decided to make a single generic function template that has for its arguments the Engine, Type, and Distribution to be used. Not an easy task especially when trying to support all of the distributions different constructors.

Comment: Thank you for the advice it might come in handy. However; I think I might go back to the drawing board, and instead of implementing static methods as such; I might just end up templating a class itself; and just store objects of them.

Comment: You can support the distributions' different constructors by a single variadic template.

Comment: So was your idea to 1) take a engine and 2) the parameters for a distribution, then 3) create a distribution object, 4) call it with the engine, and 5) return the random number? If so, this is a terrible idea, since it uses the freshly created distribution for drawing only one random number. This may often be okay, but is wasteful if the distributions have significant state, such as `normal_distribution`.

Comment: Yeah I think I figured out how to do that. I was using a version of my library from the era of Visual Studio 2008 - 2010... pre c++11. And I ported it over; and was having all kinds of problems when trying to compile it as c++17 in Visual Studio 2017 CE.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying about the distributions with their states; I was just trying to simplify the choosing of them into a single callable function through templates; but I was getting into trouble with it. I however did redesigned my class. You can refer to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay scrap that whole idea above: I went and entirely rewritten my classes into a single class. The class itself is now a class template. And it looks like this:

```
#ifndef GENERATOR_H
#define GENERATOR_H

#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

enum SeedType { USE_CHRONO_CLOCK, USE_RANDOM_DEVICE, USE_SEED_VALUE, USE_SEED_SEQ };

template<class Engine, class Type, template<typename> class Distribution>
class Generator {
public:
    using Clock = std::conditional_t<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
        std::chrono::steady_clock>;

private:
    Engine _engine;
    Distribution<Type> _distribution;
    Type _value;

public:

    template<class... Params>
    explicit Generator( Engine engine, Params... params ) : _engine( engine ) {
        _distribution = Distribution<Type>( params... );
    }

    void seed( SeedType type = USE_RANDOM_DEVICE, std::size_t seedValue = 0, std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list = {} ) {
        switch( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK:  { _engine.seed( getTimeNow() );  break; }
            case USE_RANDOM_DEVICE: { std::random_device device{};
                                      _engine.seed( device() );      break; }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE:    { _engine.seed( seedValue );     break; }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ:      { std::seed_seq seq( list );
                                      _engine.seed( seq );           break; }
        }
    }

    void generate() {
        _value = _distribution( _engine );
    }

    Type getGeneratedValue() const {
        return _value;
    }

    Distribution<Type> getDistribution() const {
        return _distribution;
    }

    std::size_t getTimeNow() {
        std::size_t now = static_cast<std::size_t>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
        return now;
    }

};

#endif // !GENERATOR_H
```

And to use it is as simple as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include "generator.h"

int main() {

    // Engine, Seeding Type, & Distribution Combo 1
    std::mt19937 engine1;
    Generator<std::mt19937, short, std::uniform_int_distribution> g1( engine1, 1, 100 );
    g1.seed( USE_RANDOM_DEVICE );
    std::vector<short> vals1;
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        g1.generate();
        auto v = g1.getGeneratedValue();
        vals1.push_back( v );
    }

    int i = 0;
    for( auto& v : vals1 ) {

        if( (i % 10) != 0 ) {
            std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << '\n' << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        }       
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Engine, Seeding Type, & Distribution Combo 2
    std::ranlux48 engine2;
    std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list2{ 3, 7, 13, 17, 27, 31, 43 };

    Generator<std::ranlux48, unsigned, std::binomial_distribution> g2( engine2, 50, 0.75 );
    g2.seed( USE_SEED_SEQ, std::size_t(7), list2 );

    std::vector<unsigned> vals2;

    for( int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        g2.generate();
        auto v = g2.getGeneratedValue();
        vals2.push_back( v );
    }

    for( auto& v : vals2 ) {

        if( (i % 10) != 0 ) {
            std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << '\n' << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        }
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Engine, Seeding Type, & Distribution Combo 3
    std::minstd_rand engine3;
    Generator<std::minstd_rand, float, std::gamma_distribution> g3( engine3, 0.22222f, 0.7959753f );
    g3.seed( USE_CHRONO_CLOCK );

    std::vector<float> vals3;

    for( int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        g3.generate();
        auto v = g3.getGeneratedValue();
        vals3.push_back( v );
    }

    for( auto& v : vals3 ) {

        if( (i % 5 ) != 0 ) {
            std::cout << std::setw( 12 ) << v << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << '\n' << std::setw( 12 ) << v << " ";
        }
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";


    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit.\n";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```